# How to refresh component on update to @Input properites

Tags: angular, input, output, ngonchanges

I am trying to refresh an angular component whenever I update the components @Input property using ngOnChanges() method but it is not working.

Scenario is as below:

I have an component called all-tasks.component whose template is defined as below:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <app-pie-chart
        (chartSelected)="filterByChartSelection($event)"></app-pie-chart>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-8">
    <h4> All Tasks </h4>
    <app-tasks [chartInput]="piechart_serviceInput"></app-tasks>
</div>
```

**app-pie-chart** component is a pie-chart component and **app-tasks** is a component hosting a HTML table with some data being consumed from a service.

Now if the user selects on any label of the pie-chart, I want the table on the right hand side to refresh with rows containing only the selected label value from the pie-chart.

For this, I have been able to successfully emit an @Output event from the **app-pie-chart** component and receive it on the **all-tasks** component.

However, I am not able to set the emitted value to the @Input element of the all-task component to refresh the table. I have used the ngOnChange() and tried to put a simple console.log statement, but even that does not print.

**Code to emit the event from the app-pie-chart**

```
@Output() chartSelected = new EventEmitter<{serviceName: string, label: string}>();
this.chartSelected.emit({serviceName: 'filterByApp', label: this.p_data.labels[event.element._index]});
```

**Code to receive the output event and set it to the @ Input attribute in app-tasks component**

**Code in all-tasks.component.ts file**

```
piechart_serviceInput: Piechart[] = [];
filterByChartSelection(selectedChartData: {serviceName: string, label: string} ) {

this.piechart_serviceInput.pop();

this.piechart_serviceInput.push({
  serviceName: selectedChartData.serviceName,
  label: selectedChartData.label
});
```

}

Here in the above code, we have set the retrieved values from the Output event to be sent in the Input parameter of the **app-tasks** component via the all-tasks.component.ts file

The definition of the Input parameter in the app-tasks component and its ngOnChange definition is as below:

```
 @Input('chartInput') chartInput: {serviceName: string, label: string};

ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
console.log('ngOnChanges was called!');
this.tasks = this.service.getTasksByLabelAndServiceName(this.chartInput.serviceName, this.chartInput.label);
console.log('Tasks component data: ' + this.tasks);
```

}

I have made sure that the Output event is getting emitted and received properly via console.log statements. However, it is in the setting to the @ Input parameters that I am finding a problem.

Can anyone please guide me ?

Is it because we are trying to set the Input attribute in the app-tasks component which is a simple javascript object with a Array type object from the all-tasks.component.ts file??

Comment: Which ChangeDetectionStrategy?

Comment: Lifecycle https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges